# Unable to cat ~9000 files using command line

Tags: cat

I am trying to cat ~9000 fasta like files into one larger file. All of the files are in a single subfolder. I keep getting the argument list is to long error.

This is a sample name from one of the files 
`efetch.fcgi?db=nuccore&id=CL640905.1&rettype=fasta&retmode=text`

They are considered a document type file by the computer.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `cat * > concatfile` as you have limits on command line size. So take them one at a time and append:

```
ls | while read; do cat "$REPLY" >> concatfile; done
```

(Make sure `concatfile` doesn't exist beforehand.)

EDIT: As user6292850 rightfully points out, I might be overthinking it. This suffices, if your files don't have too weird names:

```
ls | xargs cat > concatfile
```

(but files with spaces in them, for example, would blow it up)

Comment: Isn't `xargs` more idiomatic for this?

Comment: @user6292850: Huh, colour me surprised. I thought `xargs` would just construct a command line, which would *also* be too long - but it seems that's not what happens. I'll edit.

Comment: @NullSoulException: `REPLY` is the default `foo`. :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a limit on how many arguments you can place on the commandline.
You could use a for loop to handle this:

```
while read file;do
    cat "${file}" >> path/to/output_folder;
done < <(find path/to/output_folder -maxdepth 1 -type f -print)
```

This will bypass the problem of an expanded glob with too many arguments.